# maven tycho can not resolve project dependency

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho

I try to build my eclipse plugin-in projects by maven tycho, but it shows "cannot resolve dependencies", here are details:

1. I have two projects, one plug-in project "A", one java project "B", "A" reference the "B" indeed.
2. I write pom for them, after running "mvn package", it shows information like this.

   Cannot resolve project dependencies:
       Software being installed: A 1.0.0.qualifier
       Missing requirement: A 1.0.0.qualifier requires "bundle B 0.0.0" but it could not be found.

Comment: Either you have missing to install project `B` via `mvn clean install`or project B is not an OSGi bundle?

Comment: add another plugin "target-platform-configuration" and add the configure "<pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>" make things ok.

Comment: Sounds similar to: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6669

Comment: Can you give an example?